# Changing a variable on phone rotation with JS

Tags: javascript, html, rotation, orientation, slideshow

I've Googled and done research on how to do this, but haven't managed to make it work. I've declared a variable called width. I want my JS to check, if the width of the screen is smaller than 660px, then width shall be 140px, else it should be 100px. The variable, width, should only change when I'm rotating the device "phone", but it isn't working? I want the variable should check the width of the screen whenever i rotate the device.

JS

```
var width = 0;
   function check()
   {

if (window.innerWidth < 660) 
  {
     width = 140;
  }
  else{
    width = 100;
  }
}


window.addEventListener("orientationEvent", check);
document.write(width);
```

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to change the size of... the actual screen view, a specific element in the D.O.M.?

At first glance of your code and without knowing the specific thing you are trying to change the size of, I would say that it isn't Javascript that you should be using. You should be using a media query in CSS.

If you are trying to create a level of responsiveness to your site, I suppose you could (in theory) use some Javascript, but that is real "hackish" and not efficient coding. It may serve to slow your site down, among other things.

I will provide a generic example below, but there are two VERY important things to note. They are:

1) in the "head" section of your HTML file, you should put the following code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
```

2) where the code below mentions "orientation", you should put either "landscape" or "portrait", depending on what you mean the orientation of the phone to be.

It would look something like this:

```
@media screen and(max-width: 660px)
              and(orientation: landscape) {
                  /* In this commented out area between the 2 curly brackets, you should put the css code of the elements you want to have resize */
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks man, but the thing is that the variable I want to change in my JS is for a slideshow. So when the screen is smaller than 660px, the slideshow should move left -140px for everytime I click. Else it should move -100px.

Answer (score 1):

You could use window resize event:

Jquery:

```
$(window).resize(yourFunction);
```

Plain:

```
window.onresize = function(){yourFunction};;
```

or

```
window.addEventListener("resize", yourFunction);
```